# QField shows "unable to save features"

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, layers, qfield

I am using v3.1.0; latest version of QField. I have created my project mbtiles and tree point shapefile. The CRS for both layers are same. Tree has attributes with strings and integer values. I did put value map form in two of the string attributes and unique value for the id field. All went well until I tried to add tree points in the QField. It says

> Unable to save features

While the point is shown in the qfield and after I tried to import in qgis, it is not there.

When I mistakenly forgot to put the value map or unique value in attributes, QField did not show any message for the points added. But it took too long to enter the point's information.

What can I do for this issue?